# extjs - Change setting in property grid and save it to the server

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a property grid `Ext.grid.property.grid`. I want to use it to allow the user to change his account settings. I achieved to display custom editors, but I'm stuck to get the new value saved to the server.

```
Ext.define('Mb.view.Settings', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.property.Grid',
    alias: 'widget.settings',
    requires: ['Ext.tab.Panel'],
    title: Lang._('Options'),
    source: {
        username: Mb.user.name,
        email: Mb.settings.email
    },
    sourceConfig:{
        username: {
            displayName: Lang._('Nom d\'utilisateur'),
            editor: 'displayfield'
        },
        email: {
            displayName: Lang._('Adresse email'),
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                vtype: 'email'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I look for an event that allows me to trigger an Ajax call to the server to save the new setting, but I cannot find what I'm looking for in [the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place: it is the record that changes, meaning you have to look in the attached store: look at the store's [datachanged](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-datachanged) event and then use [store.getModifiedRecords()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getModifiedRecords).

Comment: I finally used `propertyGrid.getStore().addListener('update', function(store, record, operation, fields){if(operation == 'edit') ...})`